Why the CPU usage of process is much higher than the sum usage of those threads under the process
I have met a weird problem that the top command shows the process CPU usage is about 180%(2Cores) in Pod, but the sum of CPU usage from those threads under this process is only 120%, how can it happen and what is the external CPU usage used for? The program is just doing stream process to write data to redis(Lettuce pool) using ParallelStream in JDK8, I can see the ForkJoinPool.commonPool have 3 threads working on the stream.
I tried compare the top CPU usage with the prometheus CPU data, and they are quite closed. So the top output CPU usage should be right.

Runtime counters of a process contains also runtimes of threads that are already terminated. Are you sure that all started threads of the process are still running?
